# during startup program exited normally. segmentation fault

Tags: c++, ubuntu, docker, amazon-ec2

I am able to run my C++ program on my local ubuntu vm. But when I try to compile it and run in a docker *ubuntu:12.04/14.04/16.04/16.10* container or *AWS EC2 ubuntu 16.04 vm*, it gives *Segmentation fault* as soon as I run the program. When I try to debug using *gdb* : `break main; run` says `during startup program exited normally`

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809174/gdb-ignores-my-breakpoints) question, I tried to compile it and run on different ubuntu versions containers:12.04,14.04,16.04,16.10. It gave same error in all of them.

**CMakeLists.txt of my program for reference**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
include(GNUInstallDirs)
project (ferryfair)
IF (DEFINED _DEBUG)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_DEBUG=${_DEBUG})
ENDIF()
set (VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set (VERSION_MINOR 0)
set (Umbrella "ferryfair")
IF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")
# Mac OS X specific code
SET(macOS ON)
ENDIF(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} MATCHES "Darwin")

set (GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-std=c++11")
set (GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "-fPIC -Wl,-unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs")
IF (DEFINED _DEBUG)
set (GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS} -g")
set (GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS "${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS} -g")
ENDIF()
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}")
set (CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}")
file(GLOB HEADERS *.h)
file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)
include_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_INCLUDEDIR}/${Umbrella})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} websockets FFJSON logger ferrybase pthread ssl crypto)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${VERSION_MAJOR}
    )
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
install(FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.json"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR}
    RENAME ${PROJECT_NAME}.json)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/init.conf"
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR}/init
    RENAME ${PROJECT_NAME}.init)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/init.override"
    DESTINATION /etc/init
    RENAME ${PROJECT_NAME}.override)
```

--Update--
segmentation fault is due to the error in my code and I fixed it. But I didn't understand why gdb doesn't break at main.

Comment: try gdb?  does ldd show everything is fine?

Comment: Perhaps you have an uninitialized pointer? Debuggers normally initialize data to zero, so e.g. a pointer becomes a null pointer. If you check for null pointers you will catch the that, but uninitialized data is otherwise *indeterminate* and might be seemingly random and most likely not null.

Comment: And you can have startup problems if you have global variables that performs undefined behavior on initialization. like e.g. using uninitialized pointers.

Comment: In C++, if you have global objects, their constructors will be invoked before `main`, and if there is an issue with the construction of such objects, you can cause things to happen such as seg faults.  You need to debug your program.

Comment: Paul makes a good point. Might be useful to read about the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)